Retrieving file-properties (duration) of .mpga - audio-files from the command-line
I have a bunch of audio-files in the .mpga - format and I want to get some of their properties into a text-file. Especially I would like to collect their durations (playing lengths). I can get them using the GUI - File-properties tool (as can be seen from the screenshots), but this is a time-consuming process even when using the keyboard.
basic file properties in the GUI
audio file properties in the GUI
So I decided to write a bash-script which should extract the desired information automatically, but I could not find any bash program that can do this. I tried "stat filename", but this does not yield the playing duration for that file, as can be seen in the following screenshot:
file properties via bash: stat filename
(I also looked at man stat, but there seems to be no option to get this information either...)
I could try to write a program myself (in Java or python) reading the file-header, as I would do this with a .wav-file (where I could calculated the desired length from the header information), but I couldn't find anything about the file-header structure for .mpga - files (seems to be a proprietary format?). Anyway, any hint about this might also be helpful.
Many thanks for any help.
(I am using ubuntu linux)
(I checked question #8933053/, but none of the commands posted there worked on my system, and I am not sure, whether they help for mpga - format)

Try exiftool, ffprobe, mediainfo, they all work fine.
